# Getting ValueError after last iteration when using .apply() method

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a function to query emotion analysis from senpy by passing reviews. I printed every line with index to see if it just worked fine. The dataset has 5684 rows. However, when reaching the last row I get a ValueError. I also tried to add this last review to my function and I received the corresponding values successfully.
This is the function I wrote.

```
def query_emotion(review):
    params = {'input': review}
    res = requests.get('http://senpy.gsi.upm.es/api/emotion-depechemood',
                      params=params)
    if res.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(res)

    data = json.loads(res.text)

    negative_fear = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']
    amusement = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][1]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']
    anger = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][2]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']
    annoyance = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][3]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']
    indifference = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][4]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']
    joy = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][5]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']
    awe = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][6]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']
    sadness = data['entries'][0]['onyx:hasEmotionSet'][0]['onyx:hasEmotion'][7]['onyx:hasEmotionIntensity']

    print(X[X.Text == review].index, ": ", [negative_fear, amusement, anger, annoyance, indifference, joy, awe, sadness])
    return negative_fear, amusement, anger, annoyance, indifference, joy, awe, sadness
```

I called the function using the .apply() method:

```
X['Text_negative_fear'], X['Text_amusement'], X['Text_anger'], X['Text_annoyance'], X['Text_indifference'], X['Text_joy'], X['Text_awe'], X['Text_sadness'] = X.Text.apply(query_emotion)
```

And these are the last lines from the output after calling the function:

```
Int64Index([5681], dtype='int64') :  [0.0792444511959933, 0.1580643288473154, 0.11423923859401869, 0.1399028217635615, 0.13737889283844476, 0.10330318175060896, 0.1746433112249919, 0.09322377378506547]
Int64Index([5682], dtype='int64') :  [0.08308025773764179, 0.1820866455048511, 0.09436993092693748, 0.12984061502089508, 0.1281518690206751, 0.10726563771574184, 0.19287900349802356, 0.08232604057523404]
Int64Index([5683], dtype='int64') :  [0.09470651839679665, 0.19571514056396988, 0.10608728359324908, 0.12185687329212973, 0.12744650875201016, 0.10307696316708366, 0.150327288948556, 0.10078342328620486]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-6f8cc4431e17> in <module>()
----> 1 X['Text_negative_fear'], X['Text_amusement'], X['Text_anger'], X['Text_annoyance'], X['Text_indifference'], X['Text_joy'], X['Text_awe'], X['Text_sadness'] = X.Text.apply(query_emotion)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 8)
```

Thank you for any advice that might fix this issue!

Comment: If you're using PyCharm, try setting a conditional breakpoint on the line giving the error for when you are on the last iteration. Otherwise you could just put in some code to print out exactly the value of `X.Text.apply(query_emotion)` on the last iteration. It probably won't be what you were expecting to get.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using a Jupyter Notebook for this project. Printing the value is exactly what I tried and why I added the print() function right before the return statement. The output with index '5683' is the last row of the dataset and it seems it got all values correctly returned from the API. What I do not understand is why I still get this ValueError.

Comment: since printing the last value didn't yield anything interesting, I'd try to set it up in a environment where you have a debugger, then work from there.